# Importing MVC model class in ASP.NET core MVC with angular 2 application

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on sample angular 2 application with ASP.NET CORE MVC.

Is it possible to import a model class(let's say product.cs) which is created in "Models" folder, into the angular 2 application instead of creating the same fields under product.ts file and using it in the Asp.NET Core Angular 2 application?

**What I have tried:**

I have created a typescript file which consists of same fields which are available under model class(*.cs) and worked on the application.

Although the application is working fine, I would like to know if there is any solution for reusing the code instead of creating 2 classes with same fields?

Answer (score 0):

TypeLITE is a tool we have used before to generate TypeScript interfaces from .NET classes - see http://type.litesolutions.net/